# How to push .txt.gz file to git

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I'm trying to push some sample compressed data to my repository for testing purpose but I'm getting an error. I'm using eclipse to do this.

```
pre-receive hook declined

File [SomeFile.txt.gz] violates file name pattern 
   [(\.jar)$|(\.war)$|(\.exe)$|(\.rar)$|(\.bin)$|(\.so)$|(\.gz)$].
```

I'm trying to push a bunch of compressed files.I do have write permission for that repo and I commit regularly.

Comment: There is a pre-receive hook on the remote that only accepts certain file extensions, and apparently it fails to correctly read the extension of your file. You need to examine the pre-receive hook on the remote to find out the cause. Hooks reside in `hooks` folder inside the .git directory.

Comment: Voting to close this for now, because it cannot be correctly answered without seeing the code inside the pre-receive hook.

Comment: It's an error message from the other end. Maybe rewrite what ever you're doing to gzip the original txt file at runtime?

Comment: that pre-receive hook (I don't know the code) definitely makes sense, as there is no real gain in checking a .gz compressed file (or any other non-diffable format) into git... unless you mis-use git as backup system, which probably also is not your best option.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably rlated to [`christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin`](https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin), an Atlassian Bitbucket Server plugin to check on various file attributes, like size, name.
See its [`FileNameHook.java`](https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/christiangalsterer/stash/filehooks/plugin/hook/FileNameHook.java#L91-L106).

[image: https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin/raw/master/screenshots/file-hooks-plugin-comfiguration.png]

You can ask for changing that pattern in `Settings -> Hooks -> File Name Hook`

[image: https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin/raw/master/screenshots/file-hooks-plugin-filename-hook-configuration.png]